# How to show select-app dialog through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, maps, waze

I'm working with an android wrapped app (using web viewer), and I would like to ask the user which app wants to use when pressing in address from my app.

Example pop-up in android (Spanish): https://puu.sh/EEXBK/388b01494d.png

I have tried using the google API launcher which is: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=xxx&destination=xxx&travelmode=driving 
But this opens directly maps, without asking if you want to use Waze or not.

**It is possible with Javascript?**

My targets are Maps and Waze.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks) document for opening `waze` and for `google map` check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

you can create url for each one

---

example waze:

https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17

---

example google maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=-33.712206,150.311941&zoom=12&basemap=terrain

Answer (score 0):

You can use these URLs:

```
   appleURL = "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)"
   googleURL = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"
   wazeURL = "waze://?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&navigate=false"
```

For more see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38250397/11675817)